# How to write application logs using log4j appender for kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, log4j2, kafka-producer-api

I want to stream my app log messages to kafka using log4j kafka appender.

My application is using spring boot and log4j2.

I am seeing startup log messages in the topic but not the log statements used in the application.

Did i miss anything in the log4j2 configuration?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" name="kafka-logs" 
packages="myapp.kafka.test">
<Appenders>
    <Kafka name="Kafka" topic="test-kafka-topic">
        <JSONLayout />
        <Property name="bootstrap.servers">server1,server2</Property>
    </Kafka>
    <Async name="Async">
        <AppenderRef ref="Kafka"/>
    </Async>

    <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%-7t] %F:%L - %m%n"/>
    </Console>

</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="Kafka"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="WARN" />
</Loggers>
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-log4j-appender</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Java Code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestApplication.class);
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(TestApplication.class);
  logger.info("Before Application Startup");
  application.run(args);
  logger.info("After Application Startup");
}
}
```

Logs in Kafka:

```
  {
  "thread" : "main",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "TestApplication",
  "message" : "Started TestApplication in 17.19 seconds (JVM running for 22.67)",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$Log4jLog",
  "instant" : {
  "epochSecond" : 1555422668,
  "nanoOfSecond" : 856000000
},
"threadId" : 1,
"threadPriority" : 5
}
```

Console output:

```
08:51:08.856 [main] INFO  TestApplication - Started TestApplication in 17.19 seconds (JVM running for 22.67)
[main] INFO TestApplication - Testing my application from TestApplication
[main] ERROR TestApplication - Testing my application from TestApplication
```

Comment: Kafka batches messages. Plus you're using async appends, so very likely not all messages are flushed to Kafka immediately

Comment: I removed the async appender but still my log statements are not being pushed to kafka. I updated the sample log message in kafka and console.

Comment: I do not see appender being called for log statements. not sure if if i need any additional configuration in my log4j2.xml

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting to see exactly.

Comment: As i said, i am seeing server startup messages in kafka but not the log messages from the application like log.error or log.info messages are being ignored.

Comment: Your question seems to show `[main] INFO  TestApplication`... Sorry, I don't follow

Answer (score 4):

First you need to remove default providers for logs in your spring boot application inside  your pom.xml file, Which are Logback and perhaps Log-classic then you need to add log4j2 as new log provider and adding Kafka appender.
After adding dependencies you need xml configuration file where you can add your Kafka appender configurations.
By default you need to locate your configuration file in resource path of your project and name it as "log4j2.xml".

You can find many others [Log4j2 appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) like Cassandra or Failover appenders and add them beside your Kafka appender inside your configuration file. You can find an applicable and correct example in below.

```
<!--excluding logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


<!--adding log4j2 and kafka appender-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-log4j-appender</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Kafka appender configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="kafka-appender" packages="Citydi.ElasticDemo">

    <Appenders>

        <Kafka name="kafkaLogAppender" topic="Second-Topic">
            <JSONLayout />
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">localhost:9092</Property>
            <MarkerFilter marker="Recorder" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </Kafka>

        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} stdout %highlight{%-5p} [%-7t] %F:%L - %m%n"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="Recorder" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </Console>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="kafkaLogAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="warn" />
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think log4j2 already have the Kafka appender. As for me, I added Kafka client in gradle. So no need to add `kafka-log4j-appender`

```
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.0.1'
```

Maven should be similar

Answer (score 0):

you need to exclude the spring-boot-starter-logging as below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
             <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<appender name="KAFKA" class="org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender">
    <param name="Topic" value="logs"/>
    <param name="BrokerList" value="localhost:9092"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.apache.kafka" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="KAFKA"/>
</logger>
```